# Error wiping device: Failed to probe the device '/dev/sdb' (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-formatting

I connected my 1 year old hard drive from my old PC to my new PC, at first everything worked. Then I wanted to format it and went into the "Disks" programm. There I selected the option "Format Disk", then I selected "ATA Enhanced Secure Erase" for Erase and "No partitioning" for the Partitioning option. It formatted for a while, but after about 6 hours the process spontaneously stopped.

After restarting my computer, I wanted the hard disk to format itself further, but then an error occurred:
[Error wiping device: Failed to probe the device '/dev/sdb' (udisks-error-quark, 0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxQxR.png)

I tried the command **fsck**, which also returned an error.

```
$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
e2fsck 1.45.7 (28-Jan-2021)
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Output from **sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sdb**:

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/output error
```

If it helps, this is a SATA hard disk.

Comment: `/dev/sdb` is your whole drive. A filesystem needs to reside on a partition. Can you please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1370680/edit) and add the output of `sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sdb`?

Answer (score 1):

With a little luck you can unlock the harddisk with sudo hdparm --security-unlock "xxxx" /dev/ and then with sudo hdparm --security-disable "xxxx" /dev/ (instead of  you have to specify your harddisk in question. For example sda).

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/ng3wal/my_1tb_hdd_is_dead_please_help/

I did it, and my HDD works normaly ! :)

Comment: It would be good to point out that you mean that literally "xxxx" can work and it did in my particular case.

Comment: "sudo hdparm --security-disable "xxxx" /dev/ (instead of you have to specify your harddisk in question. For example sda)." Replace what with sda where?